# Dynamic titles in iMovie

Tags: macos, imovie, video-editing

I'm working with iMovie 11 and try to show a text list with ten rows. The viewer should be able to read all text, so the list is displayed for 20 seconds. As you can think, that will be very boring. Therefore y tried to show the list dynamicly, line per line (the previous lines will be kept, the new one will be added). The viewer can read the text and also knows how fast he should read to get the whole information.

My solution is now, to create ten titles and arrange them one after one. The first title page will contain line 1, the second page lines 1 and 2, the third page lines 1 to 3 etc. Every page will be displayed for two seconds and after this time the next page will be placed on top.

That will be much of work (i have numbers of text lists to show in this film). Does anybody knows a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: After reading your question again, I realized my answer might not be what you want. Will it work? Because I may have another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Scrolling Credits "title."

[image]

Comment: As you realized, that is not the way I want to show it. Thanks anyway. So what is your other solution you told above?

Comment: @chr Ping me in chat and we can discuss it there.